# Catching multiple values using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 <span>
    <label class="label">Color</label>
    <span class="foo"><input name="Color" value="Blue" class="customs" maxlength="100" type="text"/></span>
    </span>
 </span>

 <span>
     <label class="label">Brand</label>
      <span class="input-large"><input name="Brand" value="xxx" class="customs" maxlength="100" type="text"/></span>
    </span>
 </span>
```

I want all the input value using JS.
I wrote

```
$('.customs').each(function() {

    alert($('.customs').val());

});
```

But Every times it gives me the first input value.

```
Required Alert output: Blue, Brand
Output comes: Blue, Blue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
alert($('.customs').val());
```

with

```
alert($(this).val());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are evaluating the selector on each iteration, and I guess that when `val` is called on an array, it selects the first value.

Use

```
$('.customs').each(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Or even better,

```
$('.customs').each(function() {
    alert(this.value);
});
```

as there is no need for the layer provided by `val` here.

Answer (score 0):

double check value vs. name in your two input definitions

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a class as a selector, you're getting a collection. You can do something with it by putting it an array or iterating over it.

```
$('.customs').each(function() {
   alert($(this).val());//use this to refer to the current object
});
```